# How to write a service which checks wrong password is entered to unlock the phone...android

Tags: android

I want to use   `android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED` for writing a service which detects that wrong screen password is entered.

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: So, show us some code, because we won't do your work.

Comment: I just wanted to know that is it possible to do. As I have written the service but its not working.

Comment: The service is simply not called

Comment: Could you show some code on how you're trying to do this?

Comment: LOL!  No code for you - you have to guess what he's done and why it's not working!